# nwjs use ifream Father-son communication？

Tags: javascript, nwjs

`

```
<iframe class="iframe-content" nwfaketop src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.200:9005?code=868&pCode=868"></iframe>
```

> login storage ``

```
window.globalToken ='L19Tt8sNkCg2epK2KUWBR+qknubY5NJ1FjkFS/xH9g0QnlvroxjpDfxLUKMHiWW9RLciGyPOR/3bmdf7OVfMp9AA1JefSGHILFXMQ/oY8tBGaifBLQHeEVb0ezJbLmg/B8v2RmXDtTsdmYTXIYy63RKdwpx0hacjDN7vIfHK9uFxX7d1kDNd8NdttlBr5eqlnpW3Llt+0qAOzz2CW0NqKZCZ/OY1n91IF5+EEN9=';
```

`

> `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.200:9005?code=868&pCode=868`   Web page Obtain window.globalToken？